# Python Start Case

Tags: python, string

In JavaScript, there's a library called LoDash that provides this method:

```
_.startCase('Connor McGlynn');
// => ''Connor Mc Glynn''

_.startCase('Connor--McGlynn');
// => ''Connor Mc Glynn''
```

It essentially converts the string into a start cased string.
Is there is an elegant "pythonic" way of replicating this method.

Comment: Also the [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#startCase) provide [direct links to the source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.10/lodash.js#L14628) which should be easy to translate to Python.

Comment: @mVChr That's very helpful, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library **pydash** which is made besed on **Lo-Dash**.

Check the library from here

> https://github.com/dgilland/pydash

Documentation

> https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

In that library, you can find your desired function

```
pydash.strings.start_case(text)
```

Link

> https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-pydash.strings

Example

```
>>> start_case("fooBar")
'Foo Bar'
```